# Check if a member has Custom Status containing invite link

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I have tried multiple of the other threads posted maybe they are outdated? I'm using discord.js 14.6.0 and I'd like to check if a member has custom status containing an invite link.

Here is my code

```js
const invitelink = '.gg/VANITY';
// Status Update
client.on(Events.PresenceUpdate, (oldPresence, newPresence) => {
    const member = newPresence.member
    if(member){
        const customStatus = member.activites
        .find(activity => activity.type === 'CUSTOM_STATUS')
        ?.state
      if (customStatus) {
        if (customStatus.includes(inviteLink)) {
          console.log(customStatus)
        }
      }
    }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

In v14, you will need to use the [`ActivityType` enums](https://discord-api-types.dev/api/discord-api-types-v10/enum/ActivityType) or numbers for `activity.type`. For custom status you can use `ActivityType.Custom`.

You can import it from `discord.js`:

```js
const { Client, GatewayIntentBits, ActivityType } = require('discord.js');
```

And use it like this:

```js
const customStatus = member.activites.find(
  (activity) => activity.type === ActivityType.Custom
)?.state;
if (customStatus) {
  if (customStatus.includes(inviteLink)) {
    console.log(customStatus);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you I had made a mistake of missing the user Presence in the intents. Also, didn't know they had changed the activity stuff. Thank you! +1